# Cloudify 3.3.1 simple-manager bootstrap fails with http 504 / filename argument expected

Tags: cloudify, cloudify-script-plugin

I'm trying to bootstrap a cloudify manager using the simple-manager-blueprint from the cloudify-manager-repo and following the instructions [here](http://docs.getcloudify.org/3.3.1/manager/bootstrapping/)

I am running the bootstrap process from Ubuntu 16, and attempting to bootstrap onto an already-existing Centos 7 VM (KVM) hosted remotely.

The error I get during the bootstrap process is:

```
(cfyenv) k@ubuntu1:~/cloudify/cloudify-manager$ cfy init -r
Initialization completed successfully
(cfyenv) k@ubuntu1:~/cloudify/cloudify-manager$ cfy --version
Cloudify CLI 3.3.1

(cfyenv) k@ubuntu1:~/cloudify/cloudify-manager$ cfy bootstrap -p ./cloudify-manager-blueprints-3.3.1/simple-manager-blueprint.yaml -i ./cloudify-manager-blueprints-3.3.1/simple-manager-blueprint-inputs.yaml

executing bootstrap validation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> Starting 'execute_operation' workflow execution
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [rabbitmq_b88e8] Starting operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [python_runtime_89bdd] Starting operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [rest_service_61510] Starting operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [amqp_influx_2f816] Starting operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [manager_host_d688e] Starting operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [influxdb_98fd6] Starting operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [logstash_39e85] Starting operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [manager_configuration_0d9ca] Starting operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [mgmt_worker_f0d02] Starting operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [riemann_20a3e] Starting operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [java_runtime_c9a1c] Starting operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [elasticsearch_b1536] Starting operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [nginx_db289] Starting operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [webui_9c064] Starting operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [rabbitmq_b88e8] Finished operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [python_runtime_89bdd] Finished operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [manager_configuration_0d9ca] Finished operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [mgmt_worker_f0d02] Finished operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [nginx_db289] Finished operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [rest_service_61510] Finished operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [manager_host_d688e] Finished operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [riemann_20a3e] Finished operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [influxdb_98fd6] Finished operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [logstash_39e85] Finished operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [amqp_influx_2f816] Finished operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [webui_9c064] Finished operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [elasticsearch_b1536] Finished operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> [java_runtime_c9a1c] Finished operation cloudify.interfaces.validation.creation
2016-06-10 13:03:38 CFY <manager> 'execute_operation' workflow execution succeeded
bootstrap validation completed successfully
executing bootstrap
Inputs ./cloudify-manager-blueprints-3.3.1/simple-manager-blueprint-inputs.yaml
Inputs <cloudify.workflows.local._Environment object at 0x7fc76b458a10>
2016-06-10 13:03:45 CFY <manager> Starting 'install' workflow execution
2016-06-10 13:03:45 CFY <manager> [manager_host_cd1f8] Creating node
2016-06-10 13:03:45 CFY <manager> [manager_host_cd1f8] Configuring node
2016-06-10 13:03:45 CFY <manager> [manager_host_cd1f8] Starting node
2016-06-10 13:03:46 CFY <manager> [java_runtime_e2b0d] Creating node
2016-06-10 13:03:46 CFY <manager> [manager_configuration_baa5a] Creating node
2016-06-10 13:03:46 CFY <manager> [python_runtime_a24d5] Creating node
2016-06-10 13:03:46 CFY <manager> [rabbitmq_2656a] Creating node
2016-06-10 13:03:46 CFY <manager> [influxdb_720e7] Creating node
2016-06-10 13:03:46 CFY <manager> [manager_configuration_baa5a.create] Sending task 'fabric_plugin.tasks.run_script'
2016-06-10 13:03:46 CFY <manager> [python_runtime_a24d5.create] Sending task 'fabric_plugin.tasks.run_script'
2016-06-10 13:03:46 CFY <manager> [influxdb_720e7.create] Sending task 'fabric_plugin.tasks.run_script'
2016-06-10 13:03:46 CFY <manager> [rabbitmq_2656a.create] Sending task 'fabric_plugin.tasks.run_script'
2016-06-10 13:03:46 CFY <manager> [java_runtime_e2b0d.create] Sending task 'fabric_plugin.tasks.run_script'
2016-06-10 13:03:46 CFY <manager> [manager_configuration_baa5a.create] Task started 'fabric_plugin.tasks.run_script'
2016-06-10 13:03:46 LOG <manager> [manager_configuration_baa5a.create] INFO: preparing fabric environment...
2016-06-10 13:03:46 LOG <manager> [manager_configuration_baa5a.create] INFO: Fabric env: {u'always_use_pty': True, u'key_filename': u'/home/k/.ssh/id_rsa.pub', u'user': u'cloudify', u'host_string': u'10.124.129.42'}
2016-06-10 13:03:46 LOG <manager> [manager_configuration_baa5a.create] INFO: environment prepared successfully
[10.124.129.42] put: /tmp/tmppt9dtd-configure_manager.sh -> /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/tmppt9dtd-configure_manager.sh-7MH6NQ63
[10.124.129.42] put: <file obj> -> /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/env-tmppt9dtd-configure_manager.sh-7MH6NQ63
[10.124.129.42] run: source /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/env-tmppt9dtd-configure_manager.sh-7MH6NQ63 && /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/tmppt9dtd-configure_manager.sh-7MH6NQ63
[10.124.129.42] out: Traceback (most recent call last):
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/tmp/cloudify-ctx/ctx", line 130, in <module>
[10.124.129.42] out:     main()
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/tmp/cloudify-ctx/ctx", line 119, in main
[10.124.129.42] out:     args.timeout)
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/tmp/cloudify-ctx/ctx", line 78, in client_req
[10.124.129.42] out:     response = request_method(socket_url, request, timeout)
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/tmp/cloudify-ctx/ctx", line 59, in http_client_req
[10.124.129.42] out:     timeout=timeout)
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
[10.124.129.42] out:     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
[10.124.129.42] out:     response = meth(req, response)
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
[10.124.129.42] out:     'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
[10.124.129.42] out:     return self._call_chain(*args)
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
[10.124.129.42] out:     result = func(*args)
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
[10.124.129.42] out:     raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
[10.124.129.42] out: urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out
[10.124.129.42] out: /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/tmppt9dtd-configure_manager.sh-7MH6NQ63: line 3: .: filename argument required
[10.124.129.42] out: .: usage: . filename [arguments]
[10.124.129.42] out:


Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 2 while executing!

Requested: source /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/env-tmppt9dtd-configure_manager.sh-7MH6NQ63 && /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/tmppt9dtd-configure_manager.sh-7MH6NQ63
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "cd /tmp/cloudify-ctx/work && source /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/env-tmppt9dtd-configure_manager.sh-7MH6NQ63 && /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/tmppt9dtd-configure_manager.sh-7MH6NQ63"

Aborting.
2016-06-10 13:03:47 LOG <manager> [manager_configuration_baa5a.create] ERROR: Exception raised on operation [fabric_plugin.tasks.run_script] invocation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/k/cfyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/decorators.py", line 122, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/k/cfyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric_plugin/tasks.py", line 214, in run_script
    remote_env_script_path, command))
  File "/home/k/cfyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 639, in host_prompting_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/k/cfyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 1042, in run
    shell_escape=shell_escape)
  File "/home/k/cfyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 932, in _run_command
    error(message=msg, stdout=out, stderr=err)
  File "/home/k/cfyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/utils.py", line 327, in error
    return func(message)
  File "/home/k/cfyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/utils.py", line 32, in abort
    raise env.abort_exception(msg)
FabricTaskError: run() received nonzero return code 2 while executing!

Requested: source /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/env-tmppt9dtd-configure_manager.sh-7MH6NQ63 && /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/tmppt9dtd-configure_manager.sh-7MH6NQ63
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "cd /tmp/cloudify-ctx/work && source /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/env-tmppt9dtd-configure_manager.sh-7MH6NQ63 && /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/tmppt9dtd-configure_manager.sh-7MH6NQ63"
2016-06-10 13:03:47 CFY <manager> [manager_configuration_baa5a.create] Task failed 'fabric_plugin.tasks.run_script' -> run() received nonzero return code 2 while executing!

Requested: source /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/env-tmppt9dtd-configure_manager.sh-7MH6NQ63 && /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/tmppt9dtd-configure_manager.sh-7MH6NQ63
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "cd /tmp/cloudify-ctx/work && source /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/env-tmppt9dtd-configure_manager.sh-7MH6NQ63 && /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/tmppt9dtd-configure_manager.sh-7MH6NQ63" [attempt 1/6]
2016-06-10 13:03:47 CFY <manager> [python_runtime_a24d5.create] Task started 'fabric_plugin.tasks.run_script'
2016-06-10 13:03:47 LOG <manager> [python_runtime_a24d5.create] INFO: preparing fabric environment...
2016-06-10 13:03:47 LOG <manager> [python_runtime_a24d5.create] INFO: Fabric env: {u'always_use_pty': True, u'key_filename': u'/home/k/.ssh/id_rsa.pub', u'hide': u'running', u'user': u'cloudify', u'host_string': u'10.124.129.42'}
2016-06-10 13:03:47 LOG <manager> [python_runtime_a24d5.create] INFO: environment prepared successfully
[10.124.129.42] put: /tmp/tmpmndvAt-create.sh -> /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/tmpmndvAt-create.sh-F7IX8WT9
[10.124.129.42] put: <file obj> -> /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/env-tmpmndvAt-create.sh-F7IX8WT9
[10.124.129.42] run: source /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/env-tmpmndvAt-create.sh-F7IX8WT9 && /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/tmpmndvAt-create.sh-F7IX8WT9
[10.124.129.42] out: Traceback (most recent call last):
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/tmp/cloudify-ctx/ctx", line 130, in <module>
[10.124.129.42] out:     main()
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/tmp/cloudify-ctx/ctx", line 119, in main
[10.124.129.42] out:     args.timeout)
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/tmp/cloudify-ctx/ctx", line 78, in client_req
[10.124.129.42] out:     response = request_method(socket_url, request, timeout)
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/tmp/cloudify-ctx/ctx", line 59, in http_client_req
[10.124.129.42] out:     timeout=timeout)
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
[10.124.129.42] out:     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
[10.124.129.42] out:     response = meth(req, response)
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
[10.124.129.42] out:     'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
[10.124.129.42] out:     return self._call_chain(*args)
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
[10.124.129.42] out:     result = func(*args)
[10.124.129.42] out:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
[10.124.129.42] out:     raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
[10.124.129.42] out: urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out
[10.124.129.42] out: /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/tmpmndvAt-create.sh-F7IX8WT9: line 3: .: filename argument required
[10.124.129.42] out: .: usage: . filename [arguments]
[10.124.129.42] out:


Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 2 while executing!
^C
(cfyenv) k@ubuntu1:~/cloudify/cloudify-manager$ ^C
```

As far as I can tell it looks like the bootstrap scripts are expecting something to be listening http on the target manager host but it's not there, but of course I could be way off track as I'm new to cloudify.

I've made only minimal changes to the blueprints input:

```
(cfyenv) k@ubuntu1:~/cloudify/cloudify-manager/cloudify-manager-blueprints-3.3.1$ cat ./simple-manager-blueprint-inputs.yaml
#############################
# Provider specific Inputs
#############################

# The public IP of the manager to which the CLI will connect.
public_ip: '<my target hosts ip>'

# The manager's private IP address. This is the address which will be used by the
# application hosts to connect to the Manager's fileserver and message broker.
private_ip: '<my target hosts ip>'

# SSH user used to connect to the manager
ssh_user: 'cloudify'

# SSH key path used to connect to the manager
ssh_key_filename: '/home/k/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'

# This is the user with which the Manager will try to connect to the application hosts.
agents_user: 'cloudify'
#resources_prefix: ''

#############################
# Security Settings
#############################
# Cloudify REST security is disabled by default. To disable security, set to true.
# Note: If security is disabled, the other security inputs are irrelevant.
#security_enabled: false

# Enabling SSL limits communication with the server to SSL only.
# NOTE: If enabled, the certificate and private key files must reside in resources/ssl.
#ssl_enabled: false

# Username and password of the Cloudify administrator.
# This user will also be included in the simple userstore repostiroty if the
# simple userstore implementation is used.
admin_username: 'admin'
admin_password: '<my admin password>'

#insecure_endpoints_disabled: false

#############################
# Agent Packages
#############################

# The key names must be in the format: distro_release_agent (e.g. ubuntu_trusty_agent)
# as the key is what's used to name the file, which later allows our
# agent installer to identify it for your distro and release automatically.
# Note that the windows agent key name MUST be `cloudify_windows_agent`
agent_package_urls:
#  ubuntu_trusty_agent: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/Ubuntu-trusty-agent_3.3.1-sp-b310.tar.gz
#  ubuntu_precise_agent: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/Ubuntu-precise-agent_3.3.1-sp-b310.tar.gz
  centos_7x_agent: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/centos-Core-agent_3.3.1-sp-b310.tar.gz
#  centos_6x_agent: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/centos-Final-agent_3.3.1-sp-b310.tar.gz
#  redhat_7x_agent: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/redhat-Maipo-agent_3.3.1-sp-b310.tar.gz
#  redhat_6x_agent: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/redhat-Santiago-agent_3.3.1-sp-b310.tar.gz
#  cloudify_windows_agent: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/cloudify-windows-agent_3.3.1-sp-b310.exe

#############################
# Cloudify Modules
#############################

# Note that you can replace rpm urls with names of packages as long as they're available in your default yum repository.
# That is, as long as they provide the exact same version of that module.

rest_service_rpm_source_url: 'http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/cloudify-rest-service-3.3.1-sp_b310.x86_64.rpm'
management_worker_rpm_source_url: 'http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/cloudify-management-worker-3.3.1-sp_b310.x86_64.rpm'
amqpinflux_rpm_source_url: 'http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/cloudify-amqp-influx-3.3.1-sp_b310.x86_64.rpm'
cloudify_resources_url: 'https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-manager/archive/3.3.1.tar.gz'
webui_source_url: 'http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/cloudify-ui-3.3.1-sp-b310.tgz'

# This is a Cloudify specific redistribution of Grafana.
grafana_source_url: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/components/grafana-1.9.0.tgz

#############################
# External Components
#############################

# Note that you can replace rpm urls with names of packages as long as they're available in your default yum repository.
# That is, as long as they provide the exact same version of that module.

pip_source_rpm_url: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/components/python-pip-7.1.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm
java_source_url: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/components/jre1.8.0_45-1.8.0_45-fcs.x86_64.rpm

# RabbitMQ Distribution of Erlang
erlang_source_url: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/components/erlang-17.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
rabbitmq_source_url: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/components/rabbitmq-server-3.5.3-1.noarch.rpm

elasticsearch_source_url: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/components/elasticsearch-1.6.0.noarch.rpm
elasticsearch_curator_rpm_source_url: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/components/elasticsearch-curator-3.2.3-1.x86_64.rpm

logstash_source_url: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/components/logstash-1.5.0-1.noarch.rpm
nginx_source_url: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/components/nginx-1.8.0-1.el7.ngx.x86_64.rpm
influxdb_source_url: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/components/influxdb-0.8.8-1.x86_64.rpm

riemann_source_url: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/components/riemann-0.2.6-1.noarch.rpm
# A RabbitMQ Client for Riemann
langohr_source_url: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/components/langohr.jar
# Riemann's default daemonizer
daemonize_source_url: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/components/daemonize-1.7.3-7.el7.x86_64.rpm

nodejs_source_url: http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/components/node-v0.10.35-linux-x64.tar.gz

#############################
# RabbitMQ Configuration
#############################
# Sets the username/password to use for clients such as celery
# to connect to the rabbitmq broker.
# It is recommended that you set both the username and password
# to something reasonably secure.
rabbitmq_username: 'cloudify'
rabbitmq_password: '<my rabbit password>'

# Enable SSL for RabbitMQ. If this is set to true then the public and private
# certs must be supplied (`rabbitmq_cert_private`, `rabbitmq_cert_public` inputs).
#rabbitmq_ssl_enabled: false

# The private certificate for RabbitMQ to use for SSL. This must be PEM formatted.
# It is expected to begin with a line containing 'PRIVATE KEY' in the middle.
#rabbitmq_cert_private: ''

# The public certificate for RabbitMQ to use for SSL. This does not need to be signed by any CA,
# as it will be deployed and explicitly used for all other components.
# It may be self-signed. It must be PEM formatted.
# It is expected to begin with a line of dashes with 'BEGIN CERTIFICATE' in the middle.
# If an external endpoint is used, this must be the public certificate associated with the private
# certificate that has already been configured for use by that rabbit endpoint.
#rabbitmq_cert_public: ''

# Allows to define the message-ttl for the different types of queues (in milliseconds).
# These are not used if `rabbitmq_endpoint_ip` is provided.
# https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html
rabbitmq_events_queue_message_ttl: 60000
rabbitmq_logs_queue_message_ttl: 60000
rabbitmq_metrics_queue_message_ttl: 60000

# This will set the queue length limit. Note that while new messages
# will be queued in RabbitMQ, old messages will be deleted once the
# limit is reached!
# These are not used if `rabbitmq_endpoint_ip` is provided.
# Note this is NOT the message byte length!
# https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html
rabbitmq_events_queue_length_limit: 1000000
rabbitmq_logs_queue_length_limit: 1000000
rabbitmq_metrics_queue_length_limit: 1000000

# RabbitMQ File Descriptors Limit
rabbitmq_fd_limit: 102400

# You can configure an external endpoint of a RabbitMQ Cluster to use
# instead of the built in one.
# If one is provided, the built in RabbitMQ cluster will not run.
# Also note that your external cluster must be preconfigured with any
# user name/pass and SSL certs if you plan on using RabbitMQ's security
# features.
#rabbitmq_endpoint_ip: ''

#############################
# Elasticsearch Configuration
#############################
# bootstrap.mlockall is set to true by default.
# This allows to set the heapsize for your cluster.
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html
#elasticsearch_heap_size: 2g

# This allows to provide any JAVA_OPTS to Elasticsearch.
#elasticsearch_java_opts: ''

# The index for events will be named `logstash-YYYY.mm.dd`.
# A new index corresponding with today's date will be added each day.
# Elasticsearch Curator is used to rotate the indices on a daily basis
# via a cronjob. This allows to determine the number of days to keep.
#elasticsearch_index_rotation_interval: 7

# You can configure an external endpoint of an Elasticsearch Cluster to use
# instead of the built in one. The built in Elasticsearch cluster will not run.
# You need to provide an IP (defaults to localhost) and Port (defaults to 9200) of your Elasticsearch Cluster.
#elasticsearch_endpoint_ip: ''
#elasticsearch_endpoint_port: 9200

#############################
# InfluxDB Configuration
#############################
# You can configure an external endpoint of an InfluxDB Cluster to use
# instead of the built in one.
# If one is provided, the built in InfluxDB cluster will not run.
# Note that the port is currently not configurable and must remain 8086.
# Also note that the database username and password are hardcoded to root:root.
#influxdb_endpoint_ip: ''

#############################
# Offline Resources Upload
#############################
# You can configure a set of resources to upload at bootstrap. These resources
# will reside on the manager and enable offline deployment. `dsl_resources`
# should contain any resource needed in the parsing process (i.e. plugin.yaml files)
# and any plugin archive should be compiled using the designated wagon tool
# which can be found at: http://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/wagon.
# The path should be passed to plugin_resources. Any resource your
# blueprint might need, could be uploaded using this mechanism.

#dsl_resources:
#  - {'source_path': 'http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/fabric-plugin/1.3.1/plugin.yaml', 'destination_path': '/spec/fabric-plugin/1.3.1/plugin.yaml'}
#  - {'source_path': 'http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/script-plugin/1.3.1/plugin.yaml', 'destination_path': '/spec/script-plugin/1.3.1/plugin.yaml'}
#  - {'source_path': 'http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/diamond-plugin/1.3.1/plugin.yaml', 'destination_path': '/spec/diamond-plugin/1.3.1/plugin.yaml'}
#  - {'source_path': 'http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/aws-plugin/1.3.1/plugin.yaml', 'destination_path': '/spec/aws-plugin/1.3.1/plugin.yaml'}
#  - {'source_path': 'http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/openstack-plugin/1.3.1/plugin.yaml', 'destination_path': '/spec/openstack-plugin/1.3.1/plugin.yaml'}
#  - {'source_path': 'http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/tosca-vcloud-plugin/1.3.1/plugin.yaml', 'destination_path': '/spec/tosca-vcloud-plugin/1.3.1/plugin.yaml'}
#  - {'source_path': 'http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/vsphere-plugin/1.3.1/plugin.yaml', 'destination_path': '/spec/vsphere-plugin/1.3.1/plugin.yaml'}
#  - {'source_path': 'http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/cloudify/3.3.1/types.yaml', 'destination_path': '/spec/cloudify/3.3.1/types.yaml'}

# The plugins you would like to use in your applications should be added here.
# By default, the Diamond, Fabric and relevant IaaS plugins are provided.
# Note that you can upload plugins post-bootstrap via the `cfy plugins upload`
# command.
plugin_resources:
#  - 'http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/cloudify_diamond_plugin-1.3.1-py27-none-linux_x86_64-redhat-Maipo.wgn'
  - 'http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/cloudify_diamond_plugin-1.3.1-py27-none-linux_x86_64-centos-Core.wgn'
#  - 'http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/cloudify_diamond_plugin-1.3.1-py26-none-linux_x86_64-centos-Final.wgn'
#  - 'http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/cloudify_diamond_plugin-1.3.1-py27-none-linux_x86_64-Ubuntu-precise.wgn'
#  - 'http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/cloudify_diamond_plugin-1.3.1-py27-none-linux_x86_64-Ubuntu-trusty.wgn'
  - 'http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/cloudify_fabric_plugin-1.3.1-py27-none-linux_x86_64-centos-Core.wgn'
#  - 'http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/cloudify_aws_plugin-1.3.1-py27-none-linux_x86_64-centos-Core.wgn'
  - 'http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/cloudify_openstack_plugin-1.3.1-py27-none-linux_x86_64-centos-Core.wgn'
#  - 'http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/cloudify_vcloud_plugin-1.3.1-py27-none-linux_x86_64-centos-Core.wgn'
#  - 'http://repository.cloudifysource.org/org/cloudify3/3.3.1/sp-RELEASE/cloudify_vsphere_plugin-1.3.1-py27-none-linux_x86_64-centos-Core.wgn'
```

I'm kinda lost even knowing where to start troubleshooting. Any assistance very gratefully received

K.

Comment: 1. Can you provide the rules associated with the security group to which your VM is connected? 2. Is IPv6 enabled on the manager's VM?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you response! I'm not sure what rules you mean? I have disable the firewall. IPV6 is enabled: (cve) [cloudify@kvmlab1a ~]$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.248.42  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.248.255
        inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fefd:4c63  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:00:fd:4c:63  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
I think that the issue has to do with the proxy settings - it wants to connect to the local manager agent on 127.0.0.1 but the proxy settings are sending the request out

Comment: Yeah the more I look the more it appears to me that the cloudify bootstrap is listening to my http_proxy settings, but ignoring my no_proxy settings. I've tcpdumped traffic toward my http proxy server, it's sending traffic that way even though the cloudify proxy agent is on 127.0.0.1, and I've added 127.0.0.1 to my no_proxy environment variable

Comment: I was bootstrapping locally. I had to use a proxy to pull packages from the interwebs, but this messed up the ctx proxy running locally, as it was http and the proxy settings were making it go to the corporate proxy. I had tried setting no_proxy in my execution env but it seemed to be ignored. In the end I edited tasks.py with:       # dont proxy localhost
        env_script.write('export no_proxy=localhost')

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the document on [offline installation](http://docs.getcloudify.org/3.3.1/manager/offline/)? This should address the scenario when you need to work behind a firewall or a proxy.